# How to change the value of a color channel

Tags: java, colors

I am working on a program where I am trying to avoid more than one red color specifically (255,0,0). To add some variation and make it less likely to occur that I get (255,0,0) What I tried to do was this, but I am having trouble assigning the random variable to the specific color channel. How can I do this?

```
int x = rand.nextInt(1) + 8;
if(color.getRed() == 255 && color.getBlue() == 0 && color.getGreen() == 0){
            color.getBlue() = x;
            color.getGreen() = x;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
color.getBlue() = x;
```

makes no sense.  It's the same as trying to say "0 = x;".

If `color` references an object of a class that allows you to change its color channels, you should try:

```
color.setBlue(x);
```

However, if `color` is a `java.awt.Color`, this won't work because `java.awt.Color` is immutable.  Your only choice then would be to create a new Color object like this:

```
color = new Color(255, x, x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I started to do that I created a new Color object based on the value of the color :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all

`color.getBlue() = ...`

is illegal. You cannot assign to a function call

Second, to help you with your question: I recommend that rather than randomly generating a list of colors out of the whole range of RGB, create a few preset colors, put them into an array, and then create random colors by getting random indexes into your color array